# iOS client/server communication

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I'm looking for my iOS app to connect to other instances of itself on a LAN and send some raw data between instances (just numbers). What is the current best framework/lib to do this?

I've done this sort of thing in Windows using winsock, but iOS is a completely different world.

Bonjour? Can it be done with NSStream only? What other technologies are popular?

My Googling turns out a lot of custom wrapper, most of which could possibly be outdated at this point.

I'd prefer to use an objective-c library (vs c), but can go either way.

Any links to tuts or examples would be great! Thanks.

Also, are there any pitfalls to this on iOS that I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1):

If you've done that with winsock you may port your code to BSD sockets. Alternatively you may have a look at CoreFoundation's CFSocket - a wrapper around BSD sockets (see [Apple docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/CoreFoundation/Reference/CFSocketRef/Reference/reference.html)).

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll take a look though the docs tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Sockets work fine if you know the IP address. Bonjour is useful if you need the peers to discover each other. Then if you're sending anything that requires formatting, such as a list of numbers, I suggest [Protocol Buffers](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/). [Here's](https://github.com/booyah/protobuf-objc) an ObjC version.

Comment: This is especially appealing because I'd like to be able to function without having to know the IP addresses of all clients. In Windows I just did a UDP broadcast on a specific port, and any instance would then send a reply back and I'd then stick that IP into list of known clients. 

If this functionality is build in, that would be perfect. Thank you, I will dig in tomorrow morning.